# JxMapKit Waypoint click event

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9, openstreetmap

Hi is there a click event for the waypoints of jxmapkit? I am trying to find a way to make the waypoints clickable so when a waypoint is clicked, a frame will open.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative, I added a mouse click listener in the area around the way-point so when the area under or around the way-point is clicked, the frame will open but there are 2 problems, first the area around the way-point depend on the zoom level (You can solve this by changing the radius of the clickable area according to the zoom level) and the co-ordinates of the returned clicked location are incorrect (I still cannot find a solution to this).

Anyway Thanks.